# Probability the maximum of N samples was drawn from a given distribution?

Tags: distributions, sampling, extreme-value

I have $N$ samples and I want to know if their maximum $M$ is "significantly" higher than what you would expect -- a sort of outlier detection.  I formalize this as: I'd like to know the probability that the maximum of a sample was drawn from the same distribution as the rest.  (Is this a reasonable formalization?)

This seems difficult without knowing their distribution, so let's say it's known (in my case it's normal, but I'm estimating the parameters from the data (omitting the max), if that makes a difference), discrete, and the samples are IID (-ish).  The distribution is not bounded from above, but some reasonable bounds could be imposed if needed.

Intuitively, if I was going to take a sampling approach, I'd sample $N$ points from my distribution and see how often the max was as big as the max in question $M$.  Is this valid?

Is there a tidy closed-form solution for this?  Is it possible to do without knowing the distribution (perhaps fit a curve to the data and sample from that)?

Comment: I don't think you can talk about the probability the new observation comes from another distribution without some sort of Bayesian model.  Anyways, there are many ways of addressing this problem that don't really require a model at all.  Simply define what you consider an "ordinary" observation based on past data (standard deviations from the mean, some distance from the upper or lower quartile) and see if your new point satisfies the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-parametric approach will be limited, since it will truncate the ECDF below M. If you go parametric, then yes, you will need to first estimate the "lower group" distribution then use it to derive the distribution of the maximum. Once you do that, you can check the estimated percentile of $M$ and see if it seems unlikely.

Formally, if you have a sample of size $N$, and we assume $X_{(i)} \sim F$ for $i\leq N$, then the distribution of $X_{(N)}$ would be:

$$F_{X_{(N)}}(x) = F(x)^{N}$$

(Since $M\leq x \implies X_1 \leq x, X_2 \leq x ... X_N \leq x$)

So, if you get an estimate of $F$, say, $\hat F$, then $P(X_{(N)}\geq M|\hat F) = 1- \hat F(M)^N$ is an estimate of how likely it is that the maximum point came from the same sample as the remaining $N-1$ points.

Comment: Thank you.  Just to be clear, $F$ is the CDF, we're ordering the $X_{(i)}$ so $X_{(N)} = M$, and $F(x)^N$ is the product of the (independent) probabilities that each $X_{(i)} <= M$?

Comment: @DoctorJ you got it.